# Asyncio subscriptable problems

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to use `asyncio` library to make a requests call to some url but i am retrieving error `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable`

```
provider = []
def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    for number in list(american['mobile_number'].values):        
        url = 'https://api.telnyx.com/v1/phone_number/1' + number
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(session.get(url, ssl=False)))
    return tasks

async def get_carrier():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            provider.append(await response.json()['carrier']['name'])

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_carrier())
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Is the error says the coroutine is not subscriptiable. You probably want to await the coroutine then apply the subscript to the value that the corotinue returns. Myabe try `provider.append((await response.json())['carrier']['name'])`

Comment: thanks that work !! :) , my problem now :( is that is only coming one return from all the requests ( thinking )

Comment: can you share a sample of what `list(american['mobile_number'].values)` produces a list of so i can replicate

Comment: yes imagine is a list like this `['6613686502', '5166100971', '4436029240', '5707018841', '7049668597']`

Comment: As the code is written you’ll initiate each request asynchronously but you await each response serially. Rather than gathering all of your `get` calls you should create a coroutine that calls both `get` and `json` and gather one of those for each URL you need to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as an exmaple, I would avoid using two async loops and just do something like.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aiohttp.client_exceptions


async def get_carrier():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for number in ['6613686502', '5166100971', '4436029240', '5707018841', '7049668597']:
            url = 'https://api.telnyx.com/v1/phone_number/1' + number
            async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
                try:
                    resp_json = await response.json()
                    print(f"{number}, {resp_json['carrier']['name']}")
                except aiohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError as e:
                    print(f"{number}, Unable to find data")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_carrier())
```

**OUTPUT**
I am not sure if there is a limitation on the api and polling it too fast as the results i get are inconsistent.

```
6613686502, ONVOY, LLC - CA
5166100971, Unable to find data
4436029240, Unable to find data
5707018841, Unable to find data
7049668597, ONVOY, LLC - NC
```